# Middleware for static content in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I need to check JsonWebToken (JWT) on static contents as well.

In express.js, I tried something like this:

```
app.use(authUtil.checkAuth, express.static(config.root + '/public'));
```

The problem is, `checkAuth` has become middleware for all requests whereas I want following code to handle non-static requests:

```
app.use('/', function(req, res, next){

});
```

When I use this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(root, 'public')));
```

then `app.use('/'..`

handles all non-static requests.

What I need is to have a middleware which can handle only static requests.

Answer (score 0):

Within `authUtil.checkAuth` middleware, you will need to check if the request is static. If so, run the auth check, otherwise call `next()`.

```
// Auth middleware

const checkAuth = function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.method !== 'GET' && req.method !== 'HEAD') {
    return next();
  }

  // Parse the url and check if it's a static request
  // Not sure what to check for exactly - perhaps if it's not `/api` or something
}

// Middleware has to be set in correct order
app.use(checkAuth)
app.use(express.static(config.root + '/public'));
```

Or leave your `checkAuth` as is and only use it on specific routes. For example, if my api routes are mounted on `/api` I can add `checkAuth` to everything except `/api`:

```
app.all(/(?!\/api)/, checkAuth)
```